# How to transform solr document to list in Java

Tags: java, collections, solr, solrj

I/P : 
`SolrDocument{name=1#amit, city=2#new_york}`
`SolrDocument{name=2#abc, city=3#new_delhi}`

O/P : 
`[['1#amit','2#new_york'],['2#abc','3#new_delhi']]`

Here is the result from `Solr-4.4.0`, now I want to transform it into a `list` or `arraylist`. How can I do this?

I'm able to convert result in `Collection` but O/P is: 
`1#amit` 
`2#new_york` 
`2#abc` 
`3#new_delhi`

Comment: you can convert as json,you have to import java.lang.reflect.Type;

Comment: Can you please explain what you need to use it for? Solr API contains utility classes for most uses.

Comment: This doesn't help very much, you should post the piece of code you're using.